# Regular expression removing C-style multi-line comments

Tags: regex, perl

There is the following `Perl` code, that removes the C multi-line comments:

```
sub StripMultilineComments {
   my $string=shift();
   $string =~ s#/\*.*?\*/##sg; #strip multiline C comments
   return $string;
}
```

As I am quite new for `Perl` and regular expressions, I do not exactly understand how does it work.

Comment: Where did you find this code? Could you please file a bug report against it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, saying it works is overstating things somewhat. For example,

```
char* s1 = "/*";
char* s2 = "*/";
```

becomes

```
char* s1 = "";
```

and

```
// /*
i = 5;
// */
```

becomes

```
//
```

That said,

1. The first line declares a [sub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) and starts defining it.
2. The second line [grabs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) the first argument and puts it in `$string`.
3. The third line uses the [substitution operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) to remove the comments from `$string`.
4. The fourth line returns the transformed string.

The [pattern](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) used by the substitution operator matches

1. A `/`.
2. A `*`.
3. Any number of characters (`.*?` with /s).
4. A `*`.
5. A `/`.

The third atom matches the minimum number of characters it can (at the required position) due to the non-greediness modifier (`?`).

Comment: What does the `#` mean here?

Comment: It's being used in place of /; s#foo#fee#g is the same as s/foo/fee/g

Comment: It's the delimiter for the regex and replacement literals `s###`, `s///`, `s!!!`, `s{}{}`, etc all mean the same thing. If `/` had been used, the `/` in the pattern would have to be escaped.