# Perl one liner to remove comments, removes lines which are not comments also

Tags: regex, perl

I am using a perl one liner to remove the comments from from a C file, but it also removes the lines which have an asterik(*) in between words, for eg

```
static void *
```

Here in the one liner I am using:

```
'perl -0777 -pe ''s{/\*.*?\*/}{}gs'' ' sourceFile ' > ' destFile
```

Could anyone please suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Try with anchors.`^\*.*?\*`

Comment: Here are some problems with this particular regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16508784/2291758

Answer (score 2):

This question is answered in the perlfaq.

"How do I use a regular expression to strip C style comments from a file?"

http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file?

Comment: The perlfaq doesn't, but probably should, mention the option of using [Regexp::Common::comment](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2013031301/lib/Regexp/Common/comment.pm).  Using Regexp::Common is almost always a better option than rolling your own regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

maybe [something like this](http://regex101.com/r/gA4iU4/2):

```
s{/\*((?!\*/).)*\*/}gs
```

"Look for `/*`, look ahead to not see the `*/` sequence and eat one character, repeat the look-and-eat up until `*/`"

Be aware, however, that since the comments can be nested or  the `/* */` enclosed in quotation marks, you can never reliably parse them out with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex works for me. I just corrected your quoting, I don't know if your are using it like that, or it was a copy&paste artefact.

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{/\*.*?\*/}{}gs' sourceFile.c >destFile.c
```

(I am using `bash` on linux.)

Try it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/9AZJLe).